# equality check with more than 1 var

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
const mult = (a, b) => a * b;

const result = mult(2, 3) + mult(4, 5);

const result1 = 6 + mult(4, 5);

const result2 = 6 + 20;

console.log(result);
console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);

console.log(result === result1 === result2);
```

The expression `result === result1 === result2` equates to false when `result === result1` is true and `result1 === result2` is true.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: You will end up comparing a boolean to a number

Comment: because you have `true === 26`

Comment: First `result === result1` gets evaluated which leads to either true or false and then you compare boolean to `result2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is solved from left side to right, resolving as:

```
(result === result1) === result2;
true === result2;
```

for example, event this would fail:

```
1 === 1 === 1
```

It is due to the type conversion not done by === operator. The following resolves to true!

```
1 == 1 == 1
```

Comment: but this don't `1 == 1 == 1` (just a fun fact)

Comment: @zaynetro ninja'd! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it evaluates them in a chain.

First `result === result1` evaluates to true and then it evaluates `true === result2` which is likely false.